# Tkinter very hard to see list

Tags: tkinter, fonts, combobox, styles

Having two issues. One is that when I click on the dropdown part of my combobox all the options are super dull almost white text on white backgrounds which makes it really hard to see. 
To combat this I wanted to change the theme but also have control over the font size and colour.
However changing the font for the .config of the combobox seems to only change what is selected but the list remains the same small font.
Ive tried to change the overall theme but it doesnt seem to matter where i put it nothing changes.
Thanks

```
import os, sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
#s = ttk.Style()

#root.style = ttk.Style()
#('clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic')
root.style.theme_use("clam")
root.geometry("500x500+400+400")



# Get project list


currentprojects = './dummy/projects'
currentprojectslist = os.listdir(currentprojects)
currentprojectslist.sort()


def findshots(*args):
    try:
        project = projectmenuvar.get()
        print("Project selected: ", project)

        # get shot list
        currentshots = "{}/{}/shots".format(currentprojects, project)
        currentshotslist = os.listdir(currentshots)
        currentshotslist.sort()

        shotsmenu.set(currentshotslist[0])
        shotsmenu['values'] = currentshotslist


    except:
        print("error passing")
        pass

# def onShotChange(*args):
#     print("shot changed: ", shotsmenuvar.get())


projectmenuvar = StringVar()
projectmenuvar.trace("w", findshots)
projectmenu = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=projectmenuvar, values=currentprojectslist)
projectmenu.config(width=50,)
projectmenu.pack()



shotsmenuvar = StringVar()
#shotsmenuvar.trace('w', onShotChange)
shotsmenu = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['--None--'])
shotsmenu.config(width=50)
shotsmenu.pack()


# select the first project
projectmenuvar.set(currentprojectslist[0])


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: linux kde neon @Partho63